# NAND basic cell using structural vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I have a problem designing memory circuits in VHDL. I am trying to figure out a soultion to the following prompt:

Create a NAND basic cell in the Xilinx tools using structural VHDL methods. Add a 1ns gate delay to both NAND gates (for both rising and falling transitions). Label inputs S and R and the outputs Q and QN as appropriate. Create a VHDL test bench to simulate the circuit, driving the inputs as specified below.

De-assert both inputs at the start of the simulation. At 100ns, asset S. At 200ns, de-assert S. At 300ns, assert R. At 400ns, de-assert R. At 500ns, assert both inputs. At 600ns, de-assert both inputs. At 700ns, assert both inputs.

1. An undefined output
2. A set operation
3. A reset operation
4. A ‘0’ being stored in memory
5. A ‘1’ being stored in memory
6. A state where the Q and QN outputs are both driven to the same value
7. A metastable state

If i could get just a basic example of what the code will look like i can design a NOR circuit also (That is the actual problem i wish to solve) but a NAND example will be sufficient.

I have tried using this model for the structural code

```
 import std_logic from the IEEE library
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

    --ENTITY DECLARATION: name, inputs, outputs
    entity nandGate is
       port( A, B : in std_logic;
                F : out std_logic);
    end nandGate;

    --FUNCTIONAL DESCRIPTION: how the NAND Gate works
    architecture func of nandGate is 
    begin
       F <= A nand B;
    end func;

and this model for the test bench 



 architecture tb of nandGate_tb is
       --pass nandGate entity to the testbench as component 
       component nandGate is
       port( A, B : in std_logic;
                F : out std_logic);
       end component;

       signal  inA, inB, outF : std_logic;
    begin
       --map the testbench signals to the ports of the nandGate
       mapping: nandGate port map(inA, inB, outF);

       process
          --variable to track errors
          variable errCnt : integer := 0;
       begin
          --TEST 1
          inA <= '0';
          inB <= '0';
          wait for 15 ns;
          assert(outF = '1')  report "Error 1" severity error;
          if(outF /= '1') then
             errCnt := errCnt + 1;
          end if;

          --TEST 2
          inA <= '0';
          inB <= '1';
          wait for 15 ns;
          assert(outF = '1')  report "Error 2" severity error;
          if(outF /= '1') then
             errCnt := errCnt + 1;
          end if;

          --TEST 3
          inA <= '1';
          inB <= '1';
          wait for 15 ns;
          assert(outF = '0')  report "Error 3" severity error;
          if(outF /= '0') then
             errCnt := errCnt + 1;
          end if;

          -------------- SUMMARY -------------
          if(errCnt = 0) then
             assert false report "Good!"  severity note;
          else
             assert true report "Error!"  severity error;
          end if;

       end process;
    end tb;
```

Comment: The instructions are garbled. They start out talking about a NAND cell (not a NAND gate), then (without ever mentioning the term) switch to talking about an S-R Latch - which is presumably what they mean by "NAND cell", as it is usually built out of NAND gates. Researching "S-R Latch" should help you.

Comment: Have you just copied your entire homework assignment to Stack Overflow?? If you don't understand something *specific*, ask, clearly. If you want someone to do your homework for you, you should look elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking you to create an SR latch (called NAND basic cell in the instructions) from a cross-coupled pair of NAND gates.
The delay mentioned would be in the logic equation for the functional description of the NAND gate.

The following is a structural VHDL model of an SR latch made of two NAND gates:

```
entity nandCell is
   port( S, R  : in std_logic; --S and R are active low
         Q, QN : out std_logic);
end nandCell;

architecture structural of nandCell is 
   --NAND gate component declaration
   signal Qint, QNint : std_logic; --these internal signals are required to be able to read the "outputs"
begin
   n1 : nandGate port map(S, QNint, Qint);
   n2 : nandGate port map(R, Qint, QNint);
   Q <= Qint;
   QN <= QNint;
end structural;
```